# Insertin new column into table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table Plane where is column made_in_year (INT) and i need a new column **last_repair (datetime) NOT NULL** and it need to have condition which is **last_repair>= made_in_year** and i'm not sure how to add that condition or what syntax i should use...
I know i have to use **ALTER TABLE Plane ALTER COLUMN last_repair DATETIME xxxxxxxxx** and what should i use instead of xxxxxx?

Comment: Depends on the dbms used. ANSI SQL syntax is alter table tablename add constraint constraintname check (last_repair >= made_in_year).

Comment: Which database you are using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySql.....?

Comment: sql server @RahulTripathi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alter table Plane 
add constraint myconstraint
check(last_repair>= made_in_year)
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you wanted to add both the column and the constraint at the same time.

```
ALTER TABLE Plane
ADD last_repair DATETIME NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT repair_chk CHECK (last_repair >= made_in_year)
DEFAULT(-1);
```

Then since you wanted NOT NULL, you need to specify a default but I couldn't figure out how to set last_repair = made_in_year in that last statement, so here's an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE Plane
SET last_repair = made_in_year
WHERE last_repair = -1;
```

Comment: well when i tried to add it with not null it get error coz of the data what are already in table but as u defaultly set it on -1 it should work :) thx for helpin out :) @cricket_007

Comment: Welcome. I found it weird that the constraint is applied after the default value is entered, though.